# DIV table-cell width 100%

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```
<div style='display: table'>
    <div style='height:200px; width:100%; text-align: center; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle'>No result found</div>
</div>
```

Why is that the `width:100%` is not working? How can I solve it?

Comment: What is `display: table` ? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Aishvarya which made a div into table structure..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try giving `width: 100%` to parent so that the child has full width.

```
<div style='display: table; width:100%; background:#f00;'>
    <div style='height:200px; width:100%; text-align: center; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle'>No result found</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should explain why `width:100%;` is required also for the parent.

Comment: Also, explain why changing only the inner div to `width:1%` without giving the outer div a width, will stretch it to the full width of the window as desired.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097353/td-class-very-confused-larger-number-makes-width-smaller. It's always better to give a width to the table itself, so the browser doesn't have to geuss.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Container div must be 100%. Then we can set to child's

```
<div style="display: table; width: 100%;">
<div style="height: 200px; text-align: center; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width: 100%;">No result found</div>
</div>
```

Comment: when you give width 100%, then width is taken from parent container, and in this case there was no width

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
  <!-- it is parent div need to set width for the element -->
 <div style="width:100%;display: table;"> 
   <!-- child div, it used the parent element width if it is not set. you can specifiy your own width, if you want make it small than parent div -->
   <div style='height:200px; width:100%; text-align: center; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle'>No result found</div>
 </div>
```