# Setting custom width of div inside a table cell

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to set custom widths of div elements inside a table cell. Various questions ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19902699/1156245)) talk about `position` and `display` parameters, and I've tried too many variation to describe without success.  I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could either assist to get this minimal example working, or refer me to a specific previous answer that does actually solve this problem.  Thanks in advance.

In the example I want to set the divs as horizontal bars to reflect the values. The table is fixed with and all div ancestors set to `width: 100%`.

```css
.bar-column {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .bar {
    /* some other tested parameters.. */
    /* position: absolute; */
    /* display: block; float: left; */
    /* display: table-cell; */
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  tr { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<table width="600px" style="background-color: #ddd;">
  <tr>
    <th>Value</th>
    <th class="bar-column">Name and bar</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>20</td>
    <td class="bar-column">
      <div width="50%" class="bar"><a class="link" href="#">twenty</a></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>40</td>
    <td class="bar-column">
      <div width="100%" class="bar"><a class="link" href="#">forty</a></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td class="bar-column">
      <div width="25%" class="bar"><a class="link" href="#">ten</a></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is using width="100%" for div when you need to use style="width:100%"

So for following line:

```
<div width="100%" class="bar"><a class="link" href="#">twenty</a></div>
```

Should be:

```
<div style="width:100%" class="bar"><a class="link" href="#">twenty</a></div>
```

Apply that for lines for the div containing 50% and 25%

Comment: Thanks! I wrongly assumed the width parameter was exactly the same as using style.

Comment: The width="660px" works for table probably due to backward compatibility reasons. The style method is used *mostly* everywhere. I say mostly everywhere as there could well be rare exceptions to this - like iframe, canvas, e.t.c. So, go for style method first, if that fails, try the width="" method